# Determining a matrix to be positive definite

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to check whether a matrix is positive definite or not. I have searched on the internet on how to check it using matlab. I am interested in using the `chol` way for checking (not check the eigenvalues one). Below are the codes:

```
[~, r] = chol(A);
r == 0 && rank(A) == size(A,1)
```

I know that if `A` is not positive definite, then `r` is positive. However, what is the point of checking `rank(A)==size(A,1)`? It seems that it still works if I just use the following codes:

```
[~, r] = chol(A);
r == 0 % check if r>0
```

I wonder if `A` is positive semi-definite matrix, `r==0`. However, if I use `A=[1,0;0,0]` as an example, using the above codes for checking, `r = 2 > 0`. This makes me feel uncomfortable on checking the rank.

I found this code [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101132-how-do-i-determine-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-using-matlab).

Comment: In your case, I simply think that r is not equal to zero because 'chol' states that "if A is positive definite" not only semi-definite.

Comment: Rank deficient matrices are not positive definite, by definition. That's why your example `A` gives `r > 0` -- positive *semi*-definite is simply not considered special by `chol`. You are right that the explicit rank check is superfluous

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [1-output variant of `chol`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html?searchHighlight=chol&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)? This throws an error when `A` is not positive definite.

You can use that fact like this:

```
function itis = isPositiveDefinite(A)

    % Input checks
    errId = @(str) [mfilename ':' str];

    assert(isnumeric(A) && ~isempty(A),...
           errId('invalid_argument'),...
           'Input argument must be a non-empty numeric matrix.');

    % Initialize
    itis = true;

    % Trivial cases
    if ~isequal(A.', A) || any(~isfinite(A(:))) || any(~isreal(A(:)))
        itis = false;

    % Less trivial cases -- use chol()
    else
        try
            [~] = chol(double(A));
        catch ME
            if strcmp(ME.identifier, 'MATLAB:posdef')
                itis = false;
            else
                baseME = MException(errId('chol_failure'), [...
                                    'Failed to determine whether matrix is ',...
                                    'positive definite.']);

                throw(addCause(baseME, ME));
            end
        end
    end

end
```